# Is it possible in QML to add elements from a function?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I'd like to create some elements from a JavaScript function.

For example: I have a column with some rows, on a button click I'd like to add another row, with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Qml [list view](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-listview.html) to create this column. Then to add new element, use the [append method](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-listmodel.html#append-method) on Qml [list model](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-listmodel.html) associated with this list view.